# What kind of screws in to pressure treated plywood?

Tags: screws, pressure-treated

I am making hurricane panels for my house using the technique described [here](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/shutters/index2.html).

The plywood I purchased is pressure treated. The sliding bolts are zinc, so I assume the screws that came with them are also zinc. Is this ok, or should I be using different screws and/or bolts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not actually zinc, but zinc-coated steel, also known as galvanized steel.

The treated-wood industry recommends the use of hot-dip galvanized or stainless steel fasteners for use with treated wood.  Electroplated/electro-galvanized and mechanically-galvanized coatings should not be considered to be hot-dip galvanized. (Class 55, or higher, mechanical galvanizing provides galvanizing equivalent to the hot-dip galvanizing used on connectors and fasteners.)

Source: [Strong-Tie's pressure-treated wood FAQ](http://www.strongtie.com/productuse/PTWoodFAQs.html), which has additional information about various kinds of pressure-treated wood, galvanized steel, and stainless steel.

Comment: +1 definitely hot-dipped galvanized steel. If you don't, the screws will rust and rot. Just did this when I built my extra room.